# How to get current/selected id with link-to helper in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

In which way I can get router `:id` value from any part of code. (For example when link-to fired save current value into controller)

I have a router

```
this.resource('consultations', function() {
        this.resource('consultation',{path: '/:id'});
    });
```

And link-to to nested route

```
 {{#link-to 'consultation' item}}-{{/link-to}}
```

Route consultations

```
model: function () {return this.store.find('consultation')}
```

Route consultation

```
 model: function (consultation) {
        alert(consultation.id); //alert was shown only once, I can't remember current Id
        return this.store.find('consultation',consultation.id);
    },
```

In consultations `afterModel` I have socket connection and I need selected id  inside

```
afterModel: function () {
        socket.on('message', function (message) {
         //here I need to know current consultation ID
        });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

afterModel accepts a few arguments, the first being the resolved model. This allows you to grab the ID from it in the method body:

```
afterModel: function(resolvedModel) {
  socket.on('message', function (message) {
    var id = resolvedModel.get('id');
  });
}
```

More details can be [found in the Ember docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_afterModel).